# React Typescript how to prevent overflow scrolling

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have researched for an answer to this all over and I have not found a solution.

I have a webpage where I want to disable overflow scroll because I have an input where you can use your mouse wheel to increase/decrease the value within the input. When you start to scroll (focused or not) the page will go up or down if overflow is enabled but I need it enabled so the user can scroll down to the other inputs.

Tried css elements, react ts scrolling blockers from github repos.

Comment: I would try capturing the scroll event in javascript and stopping the effects.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) is a good post on it.